# Get the name of the current opened application in python

Tags: python, windows, time-management

I want to get the application name that is currently opened using python. This is my code

```
import win32.win32gui as win32gui
w = win32gui
window_name = w.GetWindowText(w.GetForegroundWindow())
window_name = str(window_name)
start_time = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
while True:
    new_window_name = w.GetWindowText(w.GetForegroundWindow())
    if window_name!=new_window_name:
        stop_time = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        print(f"{window_name} Time Spent: {stop_time-start_time}")
        window_name =new_window_name
        start_time = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
```

and with this, I am getting only the application heading not the application name so how do i get it.

Comment: Processes do not have names. What are you really looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) you can get the process name.

```
import psutil
import win32process, win32gui

hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
_,pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
process = psutil.Process(pid)

process_name = process.name()
```